Multiplayer Game with Multiple Unique Rooms
I'm trying to make a multiplayer dungeon-crawl game. I have the ability to make it so that every client can be inside the same dungeon, but I want it so that players can be in separate dungeons with certain people (co-op). I'm doing this in Godot .Net and want to know how I should go about this.
It's a 2d game and I am running an instance of the game on the server (for handling the collisions and game logic) -> the client only sends the input to the server and receives update pos + status + other info.
I was wondering how I could successfully do this, as from what I would imagine, I need to run multiple servers with instances of the dungeon on them.
It's a Dedicated Server with my own packet sending via UDP. I've already implemented this successfully once before in a card game, but haven't done this where the game needs to be simulated on the server with multiple different games.
Thanks in advance and lmk if you have any questions.

Usually you do not run multiple servers until you reach a bottle neck. One server runs multiple instances of your rooms. This would not be much different from your card game if it already supported that multiple persons can play the game against each other at the same time.

@Zibelas,  There is a difference between good design and good enough design.  It is much harder to scale a game after the initial design. I am not saying your comment is wrong, on the contrary it is literally quite correct, but it can be interpreted as ignore the future, until it slaps you in the face. At which point, it is too expensive to correct.

Designing for multiple servers will make scaling later much easier.
All servers can be run on a single server via separate ports and/or a field in the packet.
I would create 4 distinct server types(All servers use TCP connections(I imagine HTTPS REST style APIs), except Room uses UDP):

Login/Lobby: Authenticate user, create groups, assign room and server, create security token specific to(hash of): userID, time,roomID, server validation tokens(2FA style generated by time window), Note the Reward token must have a large time window, or be generated by the room server.
User Data(if needed):   Inventory, level, skills or any other persistent, slow change data. DB backed.
Room: Each server can host multiple rooms, this is the primary game play server. Implements game rules, replication and anti-cheat measures.
Reward: Completion(positive, negative or draw) of a room, connection passed here to tally results, provide leader-boards, swag, XP. Feeds data to User Data server.

The main point of the design is to segment the low latency game play, from the computational and storage bound aspects of the design.
The single Room server you have designed should fit into the Room role quite well, once expanded for multiple rooms. It would be a waste to run one room per server, unless there are too many players in a single room, where the network or CPU/Memory becomes the limiting factor.
